# Why Simics complaints with "Tcf error" when using reverse execution?

Tags: simics

I'm working on a hobbyist OS with Simics.
I'm running my target on simics-qsp-x86-6.0.67 machine.
When I try to use the reverse execution I got an error.
These are the steps I performed on Simics console:

```
    simics>
$disk0_image="/home/peppe/Desktop/g-os-grub2/g-os/img/c.img"
run-command-file /opt/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.67/targets/qsp-x86/qsp-hdd-boot.simics
connect-real-network-bridge
enable-debugger
add-symbol-file /home/peppe/Desktop/g-os-grub2/g-os/kernel.bin

enable-reverse-execution
bp.source_location.break kmain
bp.source_location.break process_0

simics> run
```

At some point Simics reaches the first and then the second breakpoint:

```
process_0() at /home/peppe/Desktop/g-os-grub2/g-os/process_0.c:35
35      argv[0] = argv1;

simics> rs 
[tcf error] process_work called while already processing work. This will cause unexpected behavior
```

If I press CTRL-C:

```
int_handler_ahci() at /home/peppe/Desktop/g-os-grub2/g-os/drivers/ahci/ahci.c:116
116     EXIT_INT_HANDLER(0,processor_reg)
```

Line 116 is where rs command should stop, but it happens only if I press CTRL-C.
So in order to use reverse execution, I always need to explicitly stop Simics.

My question: is there a way to fix this behavior so Simics stops itself when reaches a breakpoint?

Comment: "connect-real-network-bridge" - combining reverse with real network might have interesting effects.  Please disconnect from the real network.

Answer (score 1):

While being connected to the real network is unsupported in combination with reverse execution I would want the debugger team to have a look at this. The `simics>` prompt shows Simics has indeed stopped when you issue `rs` but what is causing the TCF issue I cannot tell now.

Comment: Interesting. So, If I understood  correctly, is there no way to use reverse debugging when the code running inside Simics receives calls from a real application running in the physical host? Example  a curl from physical machine to a web server inside Simics?